# The term 'Register-AzResourceProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Hi I am trying to teach myself Azure and I'm following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-governance/2-azure-policy. I'm on a windows 10 with `$PSVersionTable.PSEdition` = `Desktop` I messaged Microsoft support, but no one has responded. When I try to run

```
# Register the resource provider if it's not already registered
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace 'Microsoft.PolicyInsights'
```

I get

```
Register-AzResourceProvider : The term 'Register-AzResourceProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
```

I've checked off having Azure powershell installed

```
if ($PSVersionTable.PSEdition -eq 'Desktop' -and (Get-Module -Name AzureRM -ListAvailable)) {
    Write-Warning -Message ('Az module not installed. Having both the AzureRM and ' +
      'Az modules installed at the same time is not supported.')
} else {
    Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried the solution below, but I am still running into issues. It seems like to import modules I have to set powershell to unrestricted access which is not okay with me.

Comment: Well, if so, I think it's your problem, not the case itself, you will not be able to run the command without the module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve the issue, try to follow the steps below.

1.Open a new powershell session via `Run as administrator`, then run the command below.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope AllUsers -Force
```

2.After installing the module, close the administrator session and open a new normal powershell session, then login your user account which has the permission to register the provider, e.g. `Owner` of the subscription.

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

3.Then register the provider.

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace 'Microsoft.PolicyInsights'
```

[image]

**Note:** If the issue is still existing, use `Get-Module` to check if the `Az.Resources` module was imported in this powershell session(normally it will be imported automatiocally), if not, you could use `Import-Module -Name Az.Resources -Force` to import it manually.

Answer (score -1):

The command you are trying to use is not a PowerShell command. The command you are looking for should begin with either a Get- or Set- prefix.

Comment: This is not accurate; there are other prefixes used and the comand exists in the Az.Resources module, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/register-azresourceprovider?view=azps-8.0.0. To fix the issue, install the missing module, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: You can technically name your scripts or cmdlets using any combination of string characters, as following the convention of "Verb-PrefixNoun" is not necessarily required.  If you want to see a list of recommended verbs in PowerShell for this convention, you can invoke `Get-Verb`.  "Register" happens to be one of those verbs.